# Prove the duality law for events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is this law in the book I'm reading, but I can't prove it, neither can I find a proof online.
It's 'called the duality law, and it's as follows :
If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are events then: $AC + BC =(A + C) (B+C)$.

Could someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: 1. There is no reason to invoke "duality" here. 2. This "law" is false in general. // What is your source?

Comment: @Did The book I'm referring is in a foreign language, not English.
And that's how it was referred to in the book.

I too thought that it might be some kind of misprint , because (A+C)(B+C) = AC + BC + AB + C , and for the law to be true, AB + C has to equal Φ, which might be true only for some events.

Comment: So we do not know what we are talking about--except that it is probably false... :-)

Comment: Is this using the notation that $AB = A \cap B$ and $A + B = A \cup B$? If so, draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried it and they are definitely not equal.  So the "law" is false.